# Twisting a section of a vector bundle until it only has codimension $\ge 2$ zeros

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles, algebraic-vector-bundles

I am reasonably sure that the following statement is true if by a “space” we mean either a smooth quasi-projective variety or a complex manifold:

> Let $M$ be a space, $E \to M$ a vector bundle, and $\sigma$ a global section of $E$. Then there exists a unique line bundle $L \to M$ up to isomorphism such that $\sigma$ can be twisted into a section of $E \otimes L$ whose zero set has codimension $\ge 2$.

(Needless to say, all vector bundles are correspondingly algebraic or holomorphic.)

Proof for smooth quasi-projective varieties:

> Let $L = \mathcal O_M(-D)$, where $D$ is the divisor of zeros of $\sigma$ of codimension $1$. Then locally multiply $\sigma$ it times a rational function with poles along $D$, obtaining a global section of $E \otimes L$ with no zeros of codimension $1$. Obviously, if we twist $\sigma$ by a different divisor, then the result will have some codimension $1$ zeros, so $L$ is unique up to isomorphism.

Proof for complex manifolds:

> By the Weierstrass preparation theorem, the local ring $\mathcal O_{M,p}$ is a Noetherian UFD for every point $p \in M$. Hence, there exist holomorphic functions $h_j$ defined on an open cover of $M$, with the same codimension $1$ zeros as $\sigma$'s. Therefore, $\tau_j = h_j^{-1} \sigma$ only has zeros of codimension $\ge 2$.
>
> The $\tau_j$'s are related by the transition functions $g_{jk} = h_j h_k^{-1}$, which are a priori only meromorphic. However, each $g_{jk}$ extends continuously to the complement of $\tau_k$'s zero set, so, by the Hartogs extension theorem, it is a holomorphic transition function. Hence, the $g_{jk}$'s define a line bundle $L \to M$ and the $\tau_j$'s define a global section $\tau$ of $E \otimes L$.
>
> Finally, because $M$ is paracompact, the open over on which the $h_j$'s are defined may be assumed locally finite. Since $\tau$'s zero set is a locally finite union of codimension $\ge 2$ sets, $\tau$'s zero set itself is a codimension $\ge 2$ set.
>
> The uniqueness of $L$ follows from the same argument as in the algebraic case.

1. Are these proofs correct?
2. The proof for complex manifolds was horribly verbose. Can I just reuse the proof for smooth quasi-projective varieties in the complex manifold case?
3. Does the proof for smooth-quasi projective varieties also work for a larger class of algebraic varieties? (I guess what I am asking is essentially “when does a Weil divisor uniquely determine a Cartier divisor?”)

Comment: So you’re assuming $E$ has a nontrivial holomorphic section to start with? It’s rare for a bundle of rank $\ge 2$ to have any section whose zero set is a divisor.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, I am assuming that a nonzero section of $E$ is given. I'm aware that its zeros don't need to form a pure codimension $1$ subset (or perhaps I should be talking about the support in the module theory sense?), but in some sense I can “collect the codimension $1$ parts”, even if there is some “codimension $\ge 2$ remainder” left, right?

Comment: Do you have any example of codimension 1 aside from a section $(s,s)$of $L\oplus L$? Say an indecomposable rank 2 bundle?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Sure. Suppose we have a holomorphic foliation by curves $\mathscr F$ (possibly with singularities) on a complex manifold $M$ given by local vector fields $X_j$, i.e., by a global section of $E = TM \otimes L$, where $L$ is the line bundle determined by the transition functions between any pair $X_j$ and $X_k$. (cont'd)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Now let $H \subset M$ be a hypersurface given by local equations $h_j$. Replace the $X_j$'s with the products $Y_j = h_j X_j$. Then the $Y_j$'s glue up to a global section of $E \otimes \mathcal O_M(H)$, which has codimension $1$ zeros along $H$, in addition to the original codimension $\ge 2$ zeros of $\mathscr F$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: In fact, this is the main example that motivates me.